# Recover data from old disks that are now in raid

Tags: data-recovery, raid

I have moved two 1TB windows drivers into my Linux PC and made them RAID 1.
But I remembered that had one file of one of those disks. Is it possible to scan the disks without breaking Linux partitions, and trying to recover my file from formatted disk?

The reason I do not want to break the partitions is that I have already rewritten 240GB of data to that RAID 1 and I have configurated most of the Ubuntu.

When the disks were in windows PC they were not in RAID.

The drives where the file should be are /dev/sda and /dev/sdc.
With testdisk I can find my old partition on /dev/sda
[/dev/sda ms partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBonr.png)
and from /dev/sdc
[/dev/sdc ms partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bp3Ij.png)

the testdisk only gives me option to write partition structure to disk.

Any help or is my only hope to recreate the partition?
Or should I backup my data and RAID somewhere and then recreate the partitions?

Comment: Both Testdisk and Photorec (install with the same package) can find and recover single files.  Best to look through their documentation on how to recover files and not partitions.  https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk and https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec

Comment: I concur with Terrance. `testdisk` can recover individual files if you choose the `[Advanced] File System Utils` option after setting the partition type. The scan will take a bit of time but, if there's anything left to recover, `testdisk` will find it.

Comment: Thank you! I have now photorec running on both disks. And recovery disk is SSD. I chosed only .dat files.